# Как обойти re-render карточек с вложенными элементами?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-native

Я создал мобильное приложение. В нем есть список карточек, которые в себе содержат список товаров. Первоначально товары содержат неполную информацию. У нас будет один reducer - **cards**. В нем первоначальный state будет таким:

```
state = {};
```

Когда мы заходим в мобильное приложение, мы стягиваем карточки с товарами, после этого наш state преобразуется в:

```
state = {
    flowers: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Rose"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Cactus"
        }
    ],
    …
}
```

Когда я нажимаю на какой нибудь товар, например “Rose”, то я получаю из ответа API дополнительную информацию об этом товаре. Теперь наш state выглядит так:

```
state = {
    flowers: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Rose",
            color: "red"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Cactus",
        }
    ],
    …
}
```

После того, как я записал его в state нашего reducer, у нас происходит re-render скрина где расположены эти карточки.

**Проблема:**

Когда я изменяю всего лишь один товар в определенной карточке, то у меня происходит re-render всех карточек и всех товаров, хотя изменился только один товар в одной карточке. Когда к нам приходит в reducer триггер на изменение state, то я возвращаю новый state как { …state, … payload }. В payload я передаю:

```
flowers: [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Rose",
        color: "red"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Cactus",
    }
],
```

Наши данные меняются, поэтому у нас и происходит re-render FlatList.

Карточки расположены в FlatList с вертикальной ориентацией. Товары расположены в FlatList с горизонтальной ориентацией.

**Вопрос:**

Я понимаю, что, чтобы у нас изменился FlatList, нужно передать в него новые данные. Но можно ли как нибудь избежать re-render всех карточек и всех товаров, которые не изменились. Ведь если будет их будет много, то это вызовет сильное проседание по FPS.

Comment: redux ничего не сравнивает, сравнивает react. а для глубокой проверки объектов на равенство, можно использовать метод isEqual у lodash

Comment: @WVFFLIFE насчет redux в этом моменте я ошибся, думал о PureComponent/memo, а написал про него. Не думаете, что метод isEqual будет слишком жирным по performance? Карточек и товаров будет очень много. Данных у товара, также будет достаточно, то есть это довольно жирный объект. Есть ли какой-нибудь другой метод для решения этой проблемы?

Comment: ничего на ум не приходит. в крайнем случае можно договориться с бэкендщиком на счет пагинации и не париться)

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, пагинация по любому будет. Просто представьте, что он прокрутил довольно много карточек и товаров. Потом просто нажал на любой товар. Начался re-render наших карточек и товаров. Приложение жестко просело по FPS и вся вселенная схлопнулась в точку. Как тут не париться?)

Comment: ну так я имею ввиду совместить пагинацию + предложенный мною вариант. никаких ощутимых просадок не должно быть

Comment: можете сами написать реализацию глубокой проверки, но то что придется сверять props в shoulcomponentupdate это однозначно

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, я конечно понимаю, что нужна глубокая проверка. Но представь, что у моего товара 10+ параметров, а некоторые из них еще и вложенные, они все могут обновиться. Этих товаров в каждой карточке может быть по 20 и самих карточек также. Как быть в этом случае? Есть ли вариант без использования глубокой проверки?

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, у меня другой вопрос, что более затратно, сделать глубокое сравнение двух объектов с 10-ю параметрами (некоторые параметры в глубину ~2-3) или перендерить скрин с более 40 <View/>, 20 <Text/>, ~8 <Image/> (24x24), ~5 <TouchableOpacity/>

Comment: @Sergey ставлю на то что ререндер будет более затратный. Но вобще интересно было бы сделать тест.